# My web page alignment previously tested with no error, however after sometime when i open the alignment is messy

Tags: html, css

[image]

Previously when i used this code. It came out pretty well. However, recently when i open it, i found out that the whole alignment just went off. Is it css or html problem? How should i solve it? This is my html and css code.

```
    echo "  <div class='toship-info'>
                       <div class='toship-header'>Deliver to:    
               </div>
                                    <div class='toship-content'>
                                        <div class='toship-att'>Name :</div>
                                        <div class='toship- 
          data'>$ship_name</div>

                                        <div class='toship-att'>Address :
         </div>
                                        <div class='toship-
      data'>$ship_address</div>

                                        <div class='toship-att'>Contact No :
        </div>
                                        <div class='toship-
         data'>$ship_contact</div>

                                        <div class='toship-att'>Email :
       </div>
                                        <div class='toship-
       data'>$ship_email</div>
                                        <br><strong>*If there is any 
    inquiries please contact our Apex Store at +6(04)-3901025. </strong>
          </br>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ";
```

This is the css code.

```
.toship-header{
background: rgb(63,63,63);
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
padding-left: 15px;
}

 .toship-content{
background: rgb(238,238,238);
height: 130px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.toship-att{
width: 100px;
text-align: right;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
float: left;
padding: 3px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toship-data{
width: 500px;
text-align: left;
padding: 3px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12px;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Comment: Try adding `clear:left;` to `.toshib-att`

Comment: nothing change after adding

Comment: What about creating a minimal example? Instead of using PHP code show us the actual output.

Comment: what is the actual output you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space between "toship-" and "data" in your html code.

```
<div class='toship-info'>
    <div class='toship-header'>Deliver to:</div>
    <div class='toship-content'>
        <div class='toship-att'>Name :</div>
        <div class='toship-data'>$ship_name</div>
        <div class='toship-att'>Address :</div>
        <div class='toship-data'>$ship_address</div>
        <div class='toship-att'>Contact No :</div>
        <div class='toship-data'>$ship_contact</div>
        <div class='toship-att'>Email :</div>
        <div class='toship-data'>$ship_email</div>
        <br>
        <strong>*If there is any inquiries please contact our Apex Store at +6(04)-3901025.</strong>
        </br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No changes also after removing space

Comment: The "deliver to" is messy, but the "receipt" is not. However, both using the same html and css code. Why is it that?

Comment: I'm not sure but it might because of the inner div of the "toship-data" class is not populated.

Comment: How to write it so that it can be populated?

Comment: Post the code snippet of the actual output as Terry mentioned by right clicking the web page and then "View Page Source".

Comment: The variables in the div is empty. Try adding something inside the div instead of the variable for verification but i doubt that is the problem. Or you can try adding "background-color:red;" to the "toship-data" class to visualize the space occupied by the div.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the text align:
remove it from .toship-data
see fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vygsa1vy/2/)

```
.toship-header{
    background: rgb(63,63,63);
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    }

     .toship-content{
    background: rgb(238,238,238);
    height: 130px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .toship-data{
    width: 500px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
     }

    .toship-att{
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Comment: I have made my changes based on your above code, however result still the same for the alignment

Comment: see the fiddle and figure out what's wrong [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vygsa1vy/2/)

Comment: From the link you show, if there is changes to text-align: right or left, there will be changes to the text. However when i test to apply each left and right at a time to my php code and test on wamp server, there is no changes to it whether is left or right. Why is that?

Comment: Be sure that, as Aston mentioned, that there are no spaces between toship- and data. Try adding the "color:red;" attribute to this class to see if it applies. Else it will be a PHP error.

Comment: even when i add "color:red;", there is no red on the attribute. So it is php error?

Comment: Be ensure that there is really no space and the class names match EXACTELY. Or try replacing ".toship-data" to something simpler like ".hello" and look if it the class is being recognized. That's all I can help :)

Comment: there is really no space. when i put hello, it recognize

Comment: hmm... i dont know what's the bug in your code, but I guess it's a PHP error since the html fiddle is working

Comment: Thanks, problem solve. It is due to database empty no value. After adding values, it display perfectly